# Labeled balls and urns. Finding the probability for a specific pairing.

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

I was reading a text and came across this problem. The wording is a little terse so I'm not clear on why the result is true. Given N balls and N urns, all of which are labeled. The balls are distributed into the urns as follows:

1. A Ball is chosen from the pool of N balls, and placed into the first
   urn.
2. A second ball is chosen from the remaining set of N-1 balls,
   and placed into the second bin.
3. The rest are filled in a similar manner.

We know that the probability that ball 1 goes into urn 1 is $\frac{1}{n}$.

- What is the probability that ball 2 goes into urn 2?
- What is the marginal CDF of ball 2 in urn 2? (The answer is $\frac{1}{n}$, but I'm not sure how it's computed.)

For the first question, the answer is dependent on what happened at step 1. My thought is there are 2 cases.

- Case 1: Ball 2 is placed in urn 1. In this case, the probability that ball 2 is placed in urn 2 is 0, by definition.
- Case 2: Ball 2 is not placed in urn 1. In this case, there are N-1 balls remaining, so the probability must be $\frac{1}{N-1}$.

This leaves the probability at  $\frac{1}{N-1}$. This approach has a problem however because we can ask this question of Urn N and the answer should be afford a similar analysis. Clearly the marginal CDF for all the urns must be the same, in order to reconcile the probability of Ball N in urn N. How do we reconcile this apparent disparity?

Comment: The probability Ball $k$ goes into Urn $k$ is $\frac{1}{N}$ because all orders in which the balls are picked are equally likely.

Comment: The computation that led to $\frac{1}{N-1}$ is wrong. With probability $\frac{1}{N}$ Ball 2 is placed into Urn 1, and with probability $\frac{N-1}{N}$ it isn't. So the probability Ball 2 is placed into Urn 2 is, by reasoning close to yours, $\frac{1}{N}\cdot 0+\frac{N-1}{N}\cdot \frac{1}{N-1}$, which is $\frac{1}{N}$. But that's the long way of doing it, and it would become quite unpleasant if we dealt in the same way with Ball 5 and Urn 5.

Comment: Ok, this is the argument I was trying to remember. The argument goes, we must place a  ball urn 1 which an independent event of urn 2. Ball 2 goes into urn 1 with probability $\frac{1}{N}$ and not with probability $1-\frac{1}{N} = \frac{N-1}{N}$. Next we place a ball in urn 2. It will be ball 2 with probably 0 if ball 2 is placed in urn 1, and probably $\frac{1}{N-1}$ if ball 2 is not urn 1. Clearly a similar cancellation with work with ball 3, 4, .. is there a smarter way to arrive at this conclusion? What do you mean by " all orders in which the balls are picked are equally likely" before?

Comment: If the balls are picked one at a time, any permutation of their labels is just as likely as any other. There are $n!$ permutations, of which $(n-1)!$ have Ball 2 in position 2.

Comment: Ok, that is much clearer. In this construction, we pick an urn, and then pick it's corresponding ball. With this pair fixed,  there are $(n-1)!$ such arrangements. This is true regardless of which urn is picked. Thus we have $\frac{(n-1)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{n}$ as the probability of finding an arrangement with ball $x$ in urn $x$ $\forall x \in [0..N]$. Thank you, that is a better way to think of it.

Comment: I will comment further later, need to leave.